# webcrawler syntax error

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm a *very new python programmer,
this script will run, but it does not print anything.
Seems that data is empty, or not printing...
Thanks kindly,

```
import urllib2
i=1
while i<=1000:
    url = "http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/us" + str(i) + "tocpc.html"
    print url + '\n'
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print data
    #get the table data from dump
    #append to csv file
    i += 1
```

Comment: I get a Not Found error when visiting `http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/us1tocpc.html`.. What URLs did you want to generate?

Comment: Not all of the int from 1-1000 exist.  However, about 500 of them do.  So, i hope it can ignore if the URL does not exist.  For example: 125 does exist.

Answer (score 0):

first of all: you are importing urrlib2 but using urllib.

changing the first line to

```
import urllib
```

makes the script work for me.

also, consider using for i in range(1,1000) instead of your while loop.

Comment: Thanks! I changed to urllib and it worked for me also.  I'm not sure why urllib2 does not work, but thanks!

Comment: urllib2 works too basically, but returns an exception if a 404 is returned, so the script exits with i=1.